# How can i correct the syntax of update query with join in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

```
int i=st.executeUpdate("update tbl_loginprogrammer1
               JOIN tbl_loginprogrammer
               ON tbl_loginprogrammer1.pid = tbl_loginprogrammer.proid
        SET    tbl_loginprogrammer1.assigned = 'project3'
        where pid=(select min(proid) from tbl_loginprogrammer where planguage='java' and status='finished')");
```

It is showing an error 
 String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote.

How can i overcome this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A string literal can't span multiple lines in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=st.executeUpdate(
"update tbl_loginprogrammer1"+
"  JOIN tbl_loginprogrammer"+
"    ON tbl_loginprogrammer1.pid = tbl_loginprogrammer.proid"+
"  SET    tbl_loginprogrammer1.assigned = 'project3'"+
"  where pid=("+
"     select min(proid) "+
"    from tbl_loginprogrammer "+
"    where planguage='java' and status='finished'"+
"    )");
```